# Error al generar fila Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, laravel

tengo una linea de código que genera filas en base a una búsqueda por id, tengo un for each que se encarga de ello, si le doy datos desde el controlador, el botón funciona, si le doy los datos mediante el filtro, el botón deja de funcionar

Código del controlador(forzando datos)

```
$products = Product::all();
return view('pos.venta', compact('products'));
```

Código del controlador(filtro)

```
$products  = Product::where('id','like','%'.$request->texto.'%')->get();
return view('pos.partials.products', compact('products'));
```

For each que se encarga de generar las filas de la tabla

```
@foreach ($products as $product)
<tr>
    <td>{{$product->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$product->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$product->price}}</td>
    <td>
    <button data-id="{{$product->id}}" data-name="{{$product->name}}" data-price="{{$product->price}}"
        data-button="<button onclick='deleteRow(this)' class='btn btn-danger'>Eliminar Producto</button>" class="btn-primary btnAgregar"> Agregar a la compra</button></td></tr>
@endforeach
```

Imagen de el primer Caso (cuando le paso datos forzados desde el controlador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en este caso le di al 3er botón de la primera tabla, y se generó correctamente la fila en la segunda tabla

este es el cogido del inspector del botón que si funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora el mismo caso pero con el filtro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

le doy al botón generado y no hace nada

este es el cogido del botón que no funciona en el inspector
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de javascript que se encarga de la generación de la fila en la segunda tabla

```
    $(".btnAgregar").on("click", function () {
    var table = document.getElementById("table-body-venta-agregadas");
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var price = $(this).data("price");
    var name = $(this).data("name");
    var button = $(this).data("button");
    var html = "<tr>";
    html += "<td>" + id + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + name + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + price + "</td>";
    html += "<td>" + button + "</td></tr>";
    table.innerHTML += html;
    $(html).appendTo($("table:eq(0)").find("#table-body-venta-agregadas"));
});
```

Código js del filtro

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
document.getElementById("texto").addEventListener("keyup", function () {
    if (document.getElementById("texto").value.length > 0) {
        fetch(
            `/inicio/venta/buscador?texto=${
                document.getElementById("texto").value
            }`,
            {
                method: "get",
            }
        )
            .then((Response) => Response.text())
            .then((html) => {
                document.getElementById(
                    "table-body-venta"
                ).innerHTML += html;
            });
    } else {
        document.getElementById("table-body-venta").innerHTML = "";
    }
});
```

Código del Tbody de la tabla

```
<tbody id="table-body-venta">
  @include('pos.partials.products')
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando aplicas el filtro, por lo visto estas cargando solo una parte de la pagina donde aparecen los resultados con la vista `pos.partials.products`.

El problema se produce debido a que el contenido generado dinamicalente con el parcial no tiene registrado el evento click ya que es un nuevo elemento insertado en la pagina. (Este codigo solo funciona la carga inicial con la pagina completa, para los items creados durante la carga de la pagina).

```
$(".btnAgregar").on("click", function () {
 ...
})
```

La solucion es llamar a la mismo codigo despues de actualizar el filtro y recibir los datos. La idea seria algo asi:

```
function buscarProducto(){
  // llamar al controlador para obtener el parcial
  // insertar el parcial en el contenedor
  // volver a registrar el evento onclick
  // $(".btnAgregar").on("click", function () { ... })

}
```

Si compartes el codigo de la actualizacion al filtrar producto podria entregarun ejemplo mas especifico.

Comment: Voy a colocar el código del filtro como un edit al final

Comment: En base a lo que escribiste coloqué el onclick después del innerHTML, funcionó, muchas gracias :D